# Django get_FIELD_display in a template question

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using the regroup feature of Django to group by "team", here is my code:

```
    {% regroup show_detail.cast_set.all by team as cast_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for cast in cast_list %}
      <li>{{ cast.grouper }}
        <ul>
          {% for item in cast.list %}
            <li>{{ item.name }} </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

This works fine. However, the cast.grouper is integer field with choices, typically I would do {{ cast.get_team_display }} to render the text, not the integer. Is there anyway to do this with the grouper? If this helps whats rendering now is this:

- 2

  - Craig Mason

1

- Lindsay Price
- Nicole Lee

What it actually should be is:

- Creative Team

  - Craig Mason

Starring

- Lindsay Price
- Nicole Lee

Snippet of my model for you as well if this helps.
    STARRING = 1
    CREATIVE = 2

```
TEAM_TYPE = (
    (CREATIVE, 'Starring'),
    (STARRING, 'Creative Team'),
)

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
team = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=TEAM_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use `get_team_display` as the field to regroup on?

```
{% regroup show_detail.cast_set.all by get_team_display as cast_list %}
```

Comment: I've tried that, no luck with that either, I put a PDB in to see what was available to double check and dir() showed get_team_display in there but it seems it's not accessible from the regroup, for whatever reason. That would be very odd.